# How to remove user authentication when trying to open a file? e.g .JPG

Tags: data-recovery, root, users, authentication

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

- I have recovered some files that were deleted in a HDD when I was using Windows some time ago.
- I used **foremost** to recover my files, but the output directory ask me to type my user credentials to access the directory where my files were recovered.
- And also I need to type my password every time I want to open my images, files, etc.

Is there a way to change or remove this kind of authentication, to be able to access my files, images, etc. normally?

Comment: Are you running foremost as a user ("$" shell prompt)? Or as root ("#")? Does your user normally have access to that output directory?

Comment: you're right I'm running foremost without the sudo command. Maybe this can be the problem.